# Citation for permutation test

Tags: statistical-significance, permutation-test

I am using a permutation test to verify the statistical significance of an improvement in multi-class classification performance. What citation would be appropriate?

Would it be fine to cite "Permutation tests: ..." by Philip Good, 2000?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes if Phil covers that topic in the book.  It would be better to add the page numbers in the text where the classification error problem is addressed.